# How to prevent a redundant hit to DB in drools when an element is actually null?

Tags: performance, drools

I collect some object from the drools session and query it if some property != null.
It hits the database only when the property is actually null.
Why is that, And how to prevent this from happening ?

> $transaction: Transaction(account != null)

Comment: Do provide some code, and clarify what you mean.

Comment: And where in the code you have shown are you hitting the database? Please provide a more meaningful example.

Comment: If I remove the account != null there is no hit to the DB.  If account != null is in the code and the account on the Transaction is actually null so there will be a hit to the db.